# WebRTC H264 video live streaming (w FFMPEG) from OpenGL

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, webrtc, h.264

I am trying to make a peer-to-peer game streaming platform. At this point I managed to capture the OpenGL frames and I have a functional Java websockets server, I can have 2 clients that establish a peer to peer connection (I have solved the STUN/TURN servers part) and transfer text at this point.

I do not quite understand how I could stream a video made out of the Opengl frames with a low latency (<100ms). The problem mainly lies in the FFMPEG part, I want to use this to encode the frames, get the result (stdin/stdout redirect for ffmpeg ?), somehow link to the the JS API of the host (maybe a local websocket to which the JS of the hoster will connect to).

I tried several FFMPEG arguements/commands with stdin and stdout pipes and they did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What WebRTC Client are you using? What is the H264 Live stream flowing into?

WebRTC in the browser has a few restrictions (just because the implementation is naive). Try doing constrained-baseline, and do a very small keyframe interval (every second is usually good for a prototype!)

If you don't have a WebRTC client you can do something like [webrtc-remote-screen](https://github.com/rviscarra/webrtc-remote-screen)

Comment: The h264 stream needs to reach the other client, so it's either going directly in the case the two clients are reachable by one another (after each of them got their "public IP" from the STUN server) or goes to through the TURN server in case of failure to reach each other with the IPs provided by the stun server.

Any suggestion regarding the encoder I could use ? Does JS have a default method that lets me encode a frame (as H264) and send it to the other client?

Comment: WebRTC requires ICE -> DTLS -> SRTP for the peers to connect, what are you using for these? 

You can use wrtc if you are looking for a server side WebRTC implementation.